# Nullable functions dependency in PHP

Tags: php, parameters, nullable

I have a legacy application in which I modified a method from

```
private function sendMail(mixed $from, mixed $to, string $subject, string $body, array $ccn = []): void
```

to

```
private function sendMail(mixed $from, mixed $to, string $subject, string $body, array $ccn = [], array $attachments = []): void
```

Now the point is, I didn't make $attachments nullable, and when I tested, the other functions that depended on them failed. Since $attachments has a default value equal to the empty array, shouldn't the functions keep running even if it's not nullable?

Also if for example I have a function like this:

```
static public final function list(
    int $type = 0,
    bool $only_on_going = false,
    ?int $id_producer = null
   )
```

what's the point if $id_producer is nullable and the first two parameters are not? Among other things, if $id_producer is nullable why assign it null by default?

I'd like to understand well about nullable and parameters assigned by default to the function.

Comment: Adding a parameter with default value at the end of the parameters list should not cause any trouble to previously declared function calls. How did the other functions *"failed"* ?

Comment: failed how, exactly? Show the code you used to call the functions, and tell us precisely what error and/or unexpected behaviour you noticed. We cannot fix vague problems with unseen code, unfortunately (that would be a great skill to have!). See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Once we have enough info, we will be pleased to try and help. You can [edit] your question. Thanks.

Comment: `why assign it null by default`...so that the caller can omit it from their argument list if they want to. Same reason you supply a default value for any function argument. If you don't, then they have to set a value in the call.

Comment: What about `?array $attachments = null`?

Comment: isn't null for objects?

Comment: Any type can be null in PHP. https://3v4l.org/ScA1G . Your own code has nullable ints, so why are you saying that null is only for objects?

Comment: Even booleans? I mean bool type?

Comment: Yes: https://3v4l.org/GI0oR

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional parameter with default value, should now provide any new issue.

Do you call your funciton by an middleware?(asking cause u show of it's private but no how u really call it, or what's happen inside function)
Don't it use somewhere reflection to workaound with needed parameters count?

Allways need to provide any type value even just NULL

```
function x($a)
{}
```

No need to provide any value, but if you provide an value
it have to be integer and will be more important then default
(can work for other numeric and booleans like funcion(true)
will be treaten like provide 1,
but it hardly depends of server and php settings can end up with error)

```
function x($a = 0)
{}
```

Will give an error since NULL isn't numeric typ
and u asked for integer so there's no default conversion

```
function x(int $a = NULL)
{}
```

If you provide an value it will use it as long is numeric or NULL, so you can give number like 30, or just NULL if it got unset for example but you need to take care of that null in function body like handle it by parsing it $a = (int)$a which gona give u 0

```
function x(?int $a = NULL)
{}
```

Keep lasts parameters nullable have a point just for case like your.
You want add new feature but don't want to check up whole library or plugin so legacy will not need to provide new parameters cause when they were coded no one thought about feature u add

Point of allow NULL can also be database for example in MySQL you can mark column with int type as nullable so it can accept NULL too (mostly used to have unificated and clear dataset, even NULL cost less bytes then just and minimal date to store so we can call it like optimization too).